# How to auto crop in CSS

Tags: css

I have this code in CSS:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6" style="">
    <img src="images/team1.jpg" alt="portfolio img" style="margin-top: 15%; max-height: 270px; width:100%"/>
    </div>
```

I need to use auto crop the image instead of compressing the image and become pixelated,
Ive tried max-height still doesnt work ? any idea for this ?

Comment: adding overflow:hidden

Comment: This doesnt work, still getting pixelated img instead of cropped.

Comment: give the surrounding `div` a size and then use `overflow:hidden` on the picture.

Comment: Thanks this works now !!!

Answer (score 1):

Style your div with `width`, `height` and `overflow:hidden`

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/650/cats" alt="portfolio img />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-lg-6" style="max-height: 500px; overflow:hidden;">
                    <img src="images/team1.jpg" alt="portfolio img" style="margin-top: 15%; width:100%"/>
            </div>
```